# How do I open a div in a separate pop up window (as opposed to a lightbox modal window)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I have a hidden div in my page. I was wondering if there is a way to open it up in a separate window as opposed to a lightbox within the same page. There are a lot of ways to do this the lightbox method, but can't seem to find a way to do it in a separate window. I am running jQuery on the page

Lets assume this is the div:

```
<style>
    #hidden {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

</style>

<div id="hidden">
    <p>I am a hidden div</p>
    <p>Hopefully i'll open up in a new window</p>
</div>
```

I tried the following method in jQuery, but it just ended up opening the same page

```
$(".button").click(function(){
            window.open('#yeah');
        });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use document.write to set the contents on your popup window:

```
var w = window.open();
w.document.write( $("#hidden").html() );
w.document.close(); //finish "loading" the page
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're using window.open incorrectly.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open

```
var windowObjectReference;
var strWindowFeatures = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";

function openRequestedPopup()
{
  windowObjectReference = window.open("http://www.cnn.com/", "CNN_WindowName", strWindowFeatures);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation. [window.ope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)n expects an url.

It is a javascript not an jQuery function.